# C++ pointers - visual studio throws exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++

```
void setToNull(int *tempPtr)
{

    int val = 25;
    tempPtr = &val;
    std::cout << "hh" << std::endl;
    std::cout << *tempPtr << std::endl;
    delete tempPtr;
    tempPtr = nullptr;
}

int main()
{ 
    int five = 5;
    int *ptr = &five;
    std::cout << *ptr;
    setToNull(ptr);
    if (ptr)
        std::cout << *ptr;
    else
        std::cout << " ptr is null" << std::endl;
    delete ptr;
    ptr=nullptr;
    return 0;
}
```

when I run this program in visual studio, an exception is thrown and this  is not running till end.Would anyone explain to me why this is happening please ? Also is this code correct ?

Comment: Please edit your post and include the error you're getting

Comment: You're trying to `delete` a pointer to something that is on the stack. You only need to `delete` when you've allocated with `new`  --- And no, the code is **NOT** correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to `delete` pointers that point to the addresses of local variables multiple times, since the pointers you are deleting will either point to `five` in main or to `val` in `setToNull`. These variables are located in the stack and will be deleted automatically when they go out of scope. If you `delete` them manually, you'll get undefined behaviour, which, among other things, can cause a crash.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to delete a pointer which is not allocated on heap, your pointer points to element which is on stack

`int*ptr = &five`

You must not delete a pointer which is allocated on stack. Allocate by `new` should only be deleted by `delete`

And one more thing you are deleting the `int *ptr` two times in your source code. Once at `delete tempPtr;`  and second at `delete ptr;` This will lead to double deletion of that pointer (in this particular code you set it to null pointer), you must check for weather it is safe to delete your pointer before deleting it.

Comment: No, this part is logically fine, since `ptr` is supposed to be `nullptr` after a call to `setToNull`, and deleting a `nullptr` is useless, but legal.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: Except that `ptr` is passed by value, not by reference, and therefore not set to `nullptr`. It's indeed a double deletion, but the suggestion in this question (check the validity) is wrong. You can't check the "validity" of a pointer. You have to **know** whether it's safe to delete it.

Comment: @MSalters, I understand that, but I was talking about what the OP apparently _was going_ to achieve, that's why I said "logically" fine, i.e. it is fine provided the OP doesn't make any mistakes in the code.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to note is that in `setToNull` you ignore the passed in pointer value altogether (you immediately assign the address of your local `int val` to `tempPtr`) so whatever you do in this function will have no effect on anything in `main` (since you also passed the pointer by value).

So now looking at what you do in `setToNull`:

```
    int val = 25;
    tempPtr = &val;
    delete tempPtr;
```

You create a local `int`, `val`, with automatic storage duration (i.e. "on the stack") - you didn't allocate the memory for it using `new`. You then assign its address to `tempPtr`, and finally you attempt to call `delete` on it. Since you didn't allocate the memory for the `val` with `new`, this is undefined behaviour and is the source of your exception.

And how about `main`? Well, you're trying to do exactly the same thing again, this time with `five`:

```
int five = 5;
int *ptr = &five;
setToNull(ptr);  // does nothing to ptr or the memory it references
delete ptr;  // you didn't use new, so delete is undefined behaviour
```

Golden rule: if you didn't use `new`, don't use `delete`.